# Multiple python packages locations

Tags: python, pip

My `python` is not detecting packages installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

Also i have some packages installed in  `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` and some in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`, these are getting detected.

How do I make sure that `packages` from all the three locations get detected ?

Comment: You may want to look into [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). It's a good way to keep packages related to your project together.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your sys.path variable, start a python shell:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
```